# jQuery: How do you check to see if a selected dropdown item is already in a textbox list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a dropdown box to the left of a select/option box.

I would like for jquery to check to see if the item already exists by value.  The value for each option won't be in any order.

Text box:

> ```
> <select id="selectbox">
>     <option value="20:32">Something1</option>
>     <option value="103:16">Something2</option>
> </select>
> ```

The dropdown will have a list of items that also share the same values.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
    $("#boxbutton").click(function () {   
       if (('#dropdownbox :selected').val() doesn't exist inside #selectbox list)
       {
           ...add dropdownbox item;  
       } else { do nothing };
    });
```

I want to make sure the function is checking the entire selectbox value list and NOT selected/highlighted entries in the selectbox.  The textbox won't always have selected entries and will need to be checked anyway.

When The user goes to the dropdown box to add another entry to the selectbox it should repeat the search.

Not having any luck using the `.length` keyword.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var value = $('#dropdownbox').val(); // :selected is unnecessary
var hasValue = ( $('#selectbox option[value="'+value+'"]').size() > 0 );
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  Once I compared the values that solved it.

Comment: If the value is complicated/unchecked, then you must escape it before you place it into the selector string. More info: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Keep one Array and put all of your values into it. Then you can easily validate your text box value with that array. 
Or you have to get all option tag value by using DOM iteration.